# Parsing data trough JS in a CSV file and pass it to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Writing a parser for a highchart sequence; but I am not sure about the syntax.

So far I've got this; which should get the file, parse each line until hit a LFCR (\n), and then for each line, should split it every time that it find a comma.

```
$.get('file.csv', function(data){

    var lines=data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items= line.split(,);
        cat.push(items[0]);
        ser.push(parseFloat(items[1]));
    });
});
```

I pass the values at column 0 to the cat [] and the values at column 1 (float) to ser[]

Then in the option I set categories to cat and data to ser in the series section.

It won't plot anything thou, just a blank chart. If I put manually some values in data : [ ]; I get the chart; which makes me think that I am not grabbing any value from the CSV file; hence my function is wrong.

The CSV file is simple: the first value is a string, the second a float, one per each line, divided by a comma.

```
mix1,0.244
red2A,0.453
pureNa,1
CaCO3,0.68
```

Comment: Here you can find example how to parse CSV: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#1

Comment: Thanks Pawel, that's the one that I used as base for my own. I've refined it (modifying the original question to add the rest of the code that I have added), altho it doesn't seems to work, except than if I use static values. Is like the csv is not read at all.

Comment: Maybe you are loading file from localhost, which doesn't work in Chrome, only in Firefox?

Comment: I use Safari; tried in FF and Chrome and it does the same. Is there a way to print content of the variables? I am kinda lost when I don't have a print statement to stdout.

Comment: Use `console.log(variable);`. Then in Chrome you can open JS console by pressing F12. Anyway, AJAX is async call, so you need to create chart inside callback, after parsing data.

Comment: Can you paste your CSV?

Comment: Sure, pasted it in the description. Thanks!

Comment: Check in you file you have no extra line (last element in the csv)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian; the file has no new lines. I am amazed at how hard is to troubleshoot such problems with web pages :) Pawel, the console.log tell me that the variable won't exist, once that the page is loaded, so as you said, I need to create the chart after parsing data, if I want to know what is going on. BTW is there an order in which functions are called? Or it goes sequentially from top to bottom?

Comment: So you need use this in the callback (after parsing data event)